# How to append float to list?

Tags: python-3.x, list

I want to append float to list, but I got an error like this:

```
<ipython-input-47-08d9c3f8f180> in maxEs()
     12    Es = lists[0]*0.3862 + lists[1]*0.3091 + lists[2]*0.4884
     13    aaa = []
---> 14    Es.append(aaa)
     15 

 AttributeError: 'float' object has no attribute 'append'
```

I guess I can't append float to list. Can I add floats to list another way?

This is my code:

```
import math

def maxEs():
    for a in range(1, 101):
        for b in range(1,101):
            for c in range(1,101):
                if a+b+c == 100 :
                  lists = []
                  lists.append(a*0.01)
                  lists.append(b*0.01)
                  lists.append(c*0.01)
                  Es = lists[0]*0.3862 + lists[1]*0.3091 + lists[2]*0.4884
                  aaa = []
                  Es.append(aaa)
```

Comment: You are trying to add the list `aaa` to the float `Es`, it should be `aaa.append(Es)`

Comment: Also note that you re-initialize and overwrite both `lists` and `aaa` in each iteration of the inner-most loop.

Comment: Oh my god... I think I'm so stupid.... I'm so sorry....

Answer (score 2):

I don't know what you want, but you are trying to append a list to a float not the other way round.

Should be

```
aaa.append(Es)
```

Answer (score 2):

The other answer already explained the main problem with your code, but there is more:

- as already said, it has to be `aaa.append(Es)` (you did it right for the other list)
- speaking of the other list: you don't need it at all; just use the values directly in the formula
- `aaa` is re-initialized and overwritten in each iteration of the loop; you should probably move it to the top
- you do not need the inner loop to find `c`; once you know `a` and `b`, you can calculate `c` so that it satisfies the condition
- you can also restrict the loop for `b`, so the result does not exceed 100
- finally, you should probably return some result (the `max` of `aaa` maybe?)

We do not know what exactly the code is trying to achieve, but maybe try this:

```
def maxEs():
    aaa = []
    for a in range(1, 98 + 1):
        for b in range(1, 99-a + 1):
            c = 100 - a - b
            Es = 0.01 * (a * 0.3862 + b * 0.3091 + c * 0.4884)
            aaa.append(Es)
    return max(aaa)
```